# set the gridline at the back of gantt when redraw in d3

Tags: javascript, drupal, svg, d3.js

i know this maybe super duper simple to you guyz but this is the last piece of my project and i am done so i already want to finish this.  here is my problem when i first load my gantt chart i draw first the axis and the gridlines before the chart it self so it appears as i desire that the gridlines is the background of my chart but when i redraw my chart there is the problem exist the gantt draw first before the gridlines so the output is the gridlines is covering the gantt chart which looks so bad. i will post my codes so you can check it. I can't pin point where i put first the gridlines. I think i need and extra eye here..........

```
d3.gantt = function() {
var FIT_TIME_DOMAIN_MODE = "fit";
var FIXED_TIME_DOMAIN_MODE = "fixed";

var margin = {
top : 50,
right : 40,
bottom : 20,
left : 120
};
var timeDomainStart = d3.time.day.offset(new Date(),-3);
var timeDomainEnd = d3.time.hour.offset(new Date(),+3);
var timeDomainMode = FIT_TIME_DOMAIN_MODE;// fixed or fit
var taskTypes = [];
var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom-5;
var width = 1200 - margin.right - margin.left-5;
var tickFormat = "%H:%M";
var keyFunction = function(d) {
return d.startDate + d.taskName + d.endDate;
};

var rectTransform = function(d) {
return "translate(" + x(d.startDate) + "," + y(d.taskName) + ")";
};

var x = d3.time.scale().domain([ timeDomainStart, timeDomainEnd ]).range([ 0, width ]).clamp(true);
var y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(taskTypes).rangeRoundBands([ 0, height - margin.top - margin.bottom ], .1);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format(tickFormat)).tickSubdivide(true).tickSize(8).tickPadding(8);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickSize(0);

var initTimeDomain = function(tasks) {
if (timeDomainMode === FIT_TIME_DOMAIN_MODE) {
  if (tasks === undefined || tasks.length < 1) {
timeDomainStart = d3.time.day.offset(new Date(), -3);
timeDomainEnd = d3.time.hour.offset(new Date(), +3);
return;
  }
  tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
return a.endDate - b.endDate;
  });
  timeDomainEnd = tasks[tasks.length - 1].endDate;
  tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
return a.startDate - b.startDate;
  });
  timeDomainStart = tasks[0].startDate;
}
};


var xAxisGrid = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.tickSize(-height + margin.top + margin.bottom, 0, 0)
.tickFormat("");

var initAxis = function() {
x = d3.time.scale().domain([ timeDomainStart, timeDomainEnd ]).range([ 0, width ]).clamp(true);
y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(taskTypes).rangeRoundBands([ 0, height - margin.top - margin.bottom ], .1);
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format(tickFormat)).tickSubdivide(true)
    .tickSize(8).tickPadding(8);

yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickSize(0);

xAxisGrid = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.tickSize(-height + margin.top + margin.bottom, 0, 0)
.tickFormat("");

};


/////////////////////////////////
//Creating the chart
////////////////////////////
function gantt(tasks) {

initTimeDomain(tasks);
initAxis();

var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

var svg = d3.select("#gantt_chart")
.append("svg")
.attr("class", "chart")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("class", "gantt-chart")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) / tasks[tasks.length - 1].endDate)
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class","tooltip")
        .style("opacity",0);





 //this is the x-axis
 svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")")
 .transition()
 .call(xAxis)
 .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor","end")
    .attr("dx", 35)
    .attr("dy", 5);
    //.attr("dx", "-.8em")
    //.attr("dy", -10)
    //.attr("transform", function(d){return "rotate(-90)"});


 //this is the y-axis
 svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").transition().call(yAxis);


// title of the gantt
 svg.append("g")
     .append("text")
     .attr("x", 300)
     .attr("y", -30)
     .attr("class","title")
     .style("font-size",20)
     .text("MINI-PM SCHEDULER GANTT CHART");

// y title
 svg.append("g")
     .append("text")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("dx", -220)
    .attr("dy", -100)
     .style("font-size",16)
     .text("HANDLER ID");

 //this is the legend part
var colors = [["RUNNING", "#669900"],["WARNING", "#ffbb33"],["DOWN", "#FF0000"]];

var legend = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend");

var circle = legend.selectAll('circle')
    .data(colors)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
        return (i * 80)+(width/2)-125;
          })
    .attr("cy", 405)
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return d[1];
     });

var legendText = legend.selectAll('text')
          .data(colors)
          .enter()
          .append("text")
          .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                return (i * 80)+(width/2)-115;
                  })
            .attr("y", 410)
           .text(function (d) {
           return d[0];
            });  

// Add X Axis grid lines
svg.append("g")         
.attr("class", "grid")
.attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")")
.call(xAxisGrid);


//this is the actual gantt
svg.selectAll(".chart")
 .data(tasks, keyFunction).enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("rx", 0)
  .attr("ry", 0)
 .attr("class", function(d){ 
 if(d.status > 75)
 { 
    return "bar-failed";
 }
 else if (d.status >= 55 && d.status <= 75){
    return "bar-killed";
 }
 else{
    return "bar-running";
 }
 }) 
 .attr("y", 0)
 .attr("transform", rectTransform)
 .attr("height", function(d) { return y.rangeBand(); })
 .attr("width", function(d) { 
     return (x(d.endDate) - x(d.startDate)); 
     })
.on("mouseover", function(d){
        div.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", .9);
        div.html("HandlerID: " + d.taskName  + "<br>" +  "startDate: " + dateFormat(d.startDate) + "<br/>" + "endDate: " + dateFormat(d.endDate) + "<br/>" + "% Insertions: " + d3.round(d.status,2) + "%")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
})
.on("mouseout",function(d){
        div.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
});
/*
 svg.append("g")
     .append("text")
     .attr("x", width / 2)
     .attr("y", 380)
     .style("font-size",12)
     .text("PERIOD");  */

 return gantt;

};

gantt.redraw = function(tasks) {

initTimeDomain(tasks);
initAxis();

    var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class","tooltip")
        .style("opacity",0);  

    var svg = d3.select("#gantt_chart");


    var ganttChartGroup = svg.select(".gantt-chart");
    var rect = ganttChartGroup.selectAll("rect").data(tasks, keyFunction);



    rect.enter()
     .insert("rect",":first-child")
     .attr("rx", 0)
     .attr("ry", 0)
 .attr("class", function(d){ 
 if(d.status > 75)
 { 
    return "bar-failed";
 }
 else if (d.status >= 55 && d.status <= 75){
    return "bar-killed";
 }
 else{
    return "bar-running";
 }
 }) 
 .transition()
 .attr("y", 0)
 .attr("transform", rectTransform)
 .attr("height", function(d) { return y.rangeBand(); })
 .attr("width", function(d) { 
     return (x(d.endDate) - x(d.startDate)); 
     });

    rect.transition()
      .attr("transform", rectTransform)
 .attr("height", function(d) { return y.rangeBand(); })
 .attr("width", function(d) { 
     return (x(d.endDate) - x(d.startDate)); 
     });  



rect.exit().remove();

rect
.on("mouseover", function(d){
        div.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", .9);
        div.html("HandlerID: " + d.taskName  + "<br>" +  "startDate: " + dateFormat(d.startDate) + "<br/>" + "endDate: " + dateFormat(d.endDate) + "<br/>" + "% Insertions: " + d3.round(d.status,2) + "%")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
})
.on("mouseout",function(d){
        div.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
});

    svg.select(".grid").transition().call(xAxisGrid);
    svg.select(".x").transition().call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y").transition().call(yAxis);

return gantt;
}; // end of redraw





gantt.margin = function(value) {
if (!arguments.length)
    return margin;
margin = value;
return gantt;
};

gantt.timeDomain = function(value) {
if (!arguments.length)
    return [ timeDomainStart, timeDomainEnd ];
timeDomainStart = +value[0], timeDomainEnd = +value[1];
return gantt;
};

/**
 * @param {string}
 *                vale The value can be "fit" - the domain fits the data or
 *                "fixed" - fixed domain.
 */
gantt.timeDomainMode = function(value) {
if (!arguments.length)
    return timeDomainMode;
    timeDomainMode = value;
    return gantt;

};

gantt.taskTypes = function(value) {
if (!arguments.length)
    return taskTypes;
taskTypes = value;
return gantt;
};

gantt.taskStatus = function(value) {
if (!arguments.length)
    return taskStatus;
taskStatus = value;
return gantt;
};

gantt.width = function(value) {
if (!arguments.length)
    return width;
width = +value;
return gantt;
};

gantt.height = function(value) {
if (!arguments.length)
    return height;
height = +value;
return gantt;
};

gantt.tickFormat = function(value) {
if (!arguments.length)
    return tickFormat;
tickFormat = value;
return gantt;
};



return gantt;
};
```

Comment: can i position the gridline as a background using css????????

Comment: in redraw function in d3 how can i draw first the axis and the gridline before the gantt???????????

Comment: In the redraw function, have you tried moving the `svg.select(".grid")` block further up so that it's rendered first?

Comment: i already tried but i could not pin point the exact place where the  gantt is redrawing.   i know i need to redraw first the gridline before the chart.  can you check my redraw function??

Comment: Without working code it very hard to debug - particularly somebody elses.  Can you post a working example? In the meantime,have you moved the block I mentioned to just below this line `var svg = d3.select("#gantt_chart");`?

Comment: yes i already did, i actually play around placing that code so that it will be draw first before the gantt itself but still no luck. Is it possible to set the gridlines at the background using CSS? the data that is plotting the gantt comes from 4 different table from my database so i can't give a working code. I can just give the codes that draw the gantt